# How to make a php file execute shell commands

Tags: php, shell-exec, git-pull

I made a php file to fetch any changes in my repository hosted on github using this code:

```
<?php
`git pull`;
?>
```

And I gave the url of this php script(hosted on my server) as a service hook url in my github settings. So it should make a post request to this php file whenever I push something to my github repository. However this doesn't seem to work.

The github help page says that they send a post request to the concerned url with some paylod. How is the script executed then?

When I do  `git pull` from the bash prompt after ssh'ing into my site, it pulls all the changes. 
File permissions for this script are currently set to 755.

What changes do I need to make for php to execute this file as a shell script?

**Edit** - I also tried changing the ownership of the corresponding folder like so:

```
chown -R apache:apache Test
```

So that when a post request is made to the url, the script is executed as the www-data user I guess and therefore the script can execute. But I get an error when I try to do this saying:

```
chown: `apache:apache': invalid group
```

Comment: Do i need to ad some more details to my question. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the PHP exec() function

```
 string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

**command** = The command that will be executed

**output** = If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements, call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().

**return_var** = If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried using both `exec` and `shell_exec` but the script doesn't seem to execute. I think this has something to do with file permissions or user access to the file.